# Catastrophic backtracking

Tags: регулярные-выражения

На больших текстах простое регулярное выражение

```
\(\[.*?\]\)
```

Вызывает ошибку "Catastrophic backtracking".
Как от нее избавиться?
[Живой пример](https://regex101.com/r/qO2xU9/8)

Comment: Приведите код и пример прямо в коде вопроса. Портянка из декомпилятора на полмегабайта маловменяемого текста — не считается.

Comment: Всё там читается и выводится данная ошибка. В вопрос пол мегабайта тоже не загрузишь, а дело именно в размере, т.к. пока данных было меньше всё работало. Нужно как-то перестроить регулярку, чтобы обойти ошибку

Comment: Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным. Ссылки недолговечны.

Comment: Что вы вообще собираетесь делать с этой регуляркой? Что осмысленное можно извлечь из этого обфусцированного трэша? Если хотите куда-то сдвинуться, натравите синтаксический анализатор, а не регулярку со скобочками.

Comment: @Discord, могу стереть после ответа, не проблема. Проблема в том, что в php 5.5 всё работает, в php 5.2 получаю пустой ответ, решил проверить в online получил эту ошибку. Я понимаю, что она в каком-то роде логична, но как её обойти?

Comment: Извлечь нужно весь массив, всё что между Array(...);

Comment: Уберите `?`.​​​

Comment: @Discord в данном случае сработает, но массив не всегда один, потому ´?´ имел место там быть. т.е. если мы скопируем текст 2 раза, то не будет найдено оба массива

Comment: Тогда ставьте жёсткие условия на начало и конец, чтобы у регулярки не возникало желание елозить туда-сюда.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/qO2xU9/2 позже оформлю как ответ с пояснениями.

Comment: На начало можно запросто по названию массива, они уникальные, а конец одинаковый у всех, ");" и из-за нежадного режима начинает скакать.

Comment: @ReinRaus, спасаешь, как обычно) Пояснения там уже есть, ищет пока чуть не то только

Comment: @Isaev вроде мое выражение полный аналог регулярки по Вашей ссылке. Ваше ищет все что внутри квадратных скобочек, причем справа от закрывающей квадратной скобочки должна быть закрывающая круглая скобочка. Вот Ваше выражение без сохраняющих групп: `\[.*?\]\)`

Comment: Ошибка была. Вот полный аналог https://regex101.com/r/qO2xU9/3

Comment: @ReinRaus, `\(\[.*?\]\)` вот так доолжно было быть без групп, опечаточка

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Минимальная квантификация `.*?` порождает множество точек возврата на больших текстах, что и приводит к упомянутой ошибке.
Стараясь захватить минимальное количество символов движок регулярных выражений на каждый символ захваченный с помощью `.*?` создает точку возврата в которую можно вернуться, если следующее за минимальной квантификацией выражение не будет найдено.

Оптимизация регулярных выражений обычно сводится к созданию регулярного выражения, которое создает минимальное число точек возврата, при этом надо четко осознавать где нужны точки возврата, а где нет.

Объяснить можно только на конкретных примерах и нет общей формулы как оптимизировать регулярные выражения.
В данном случае мы видим, что справа должен совпасть текст `\]\)`, а значит за счет сверхжадной квантификации мы сможем захватить очень много текста соответствующего всем символам, кроме `]` и создадим при этом всего одну точку возврата для всего, что совпадет с `[^\]]++` точка возврата будет сохранена только в позиции первого символа, совпавшего с `[^\]]++` и нигде внутри соответствующего текста.
Помимо **не ]** нужно еще включить закрывающую квадратную скобку справа от которой нет закрывающей круглой скобки. Ведь если бы она была, то это и было бы искомое окончание всего совпадения.

```
(?: # alternative
  [^\]]++ # not ]
  | # or
  \](?!\)) # ] without )
)*
```

Отмечу точки возврата, которые создаст это выражение:

```
[( aaaaa ] aaaaa ] aaaaa ])
  ^      ^^      ^^
```

5 точек возврата. Для полноты картины тот же текст, но с минимальной квантификацией `.*?`

```
[( aaaaa ] aaaaa ] aaaaa ])
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

23 точки возврата, почти в 5 раз больше на этом примере, но на самом деле это зависит от частоты появления **]** в тексте.

Оптимальное регулярное выражение будет выглядеть так:

```
(\(\[ # symbols ([
(  # first groop
  (?: # alternative
    [^\]]++ # not ]
    | # or
    \](?!\)) # ] without )
  )* # end alternative
) # end first groop
\]\)) # symbols ])
```

https://regex101.com/r/qO2xU9/9

---

Регулярное выражение выше оптимально, если количество **]** мало в сравнении с долей остального текста.
Если же гораздо больше символов **]** между **([** и **])**, то оптимальным будет такое выражение:

```
(\(\[ # symbols ([
(  # first groop
  (?: # alternative
    (?:
      \](?!\)) # ] without )
    )++
    |
    [^\]]++ # not ]
  )* # end alternative
) # end first groop
\]\)) # symbols ])
```

https://regex101.com/r/qO2xU9/10

---

## UPDATE. PHP 5.6 замер скорости

> непонятым осталось только поведение в самом php: Если исходное выражение preg_match_all('#([(.*?)]))#s', $text, $result); работало хотя бы на локальном сервере, то оптимальное: preg_match_all('#(([((?:[^]]++|](?!)))*)]))#s', $text, $result); вешает его наглухо... Вроде нигде не ошибся?

```
<HTML><PRE><?
$text = file_get_contents( "ParamsFish.as" );
$loops= 10000;
$t1 = microtime( true );
for ( $i=0; $i < $loops; $i++ )
    preg_match_all( '#(\\(\\[((?:[^\\]]++|\\](?!\\)))*)\\]\\))#s' , $text, $result1);
$t2 = microtime( true );
for ( $i=0; $i < $loops; $i++ )
    preg_match_all( '#(\\(\\[(.*?)\\]\\))#s', $text, $result2);
$t3 = microtime( true );
echo ($t2-$t1)."   ".($t3-$t2)."\n";
var_dump( $result1[0] == $result2[0] );
?></PRE><HTML>
```

Результат:

```
21.452227115631   141.5550968647
bool(true)
```

Второе регулярное выражение работает в 7 раз медленнее.
Почему у Вас зависает я подсказать к сожалению не могу. Возможно, что следует обновить версию PHP, возможно, что проблема кроется в чем-то другом.

P.S. Если Вы проверяли именно этим выражением `'#([(.*?)]))#s'` (как в комментарии), то оно некорректно.

Comment: Спасибо, очень познавательно!

Comment: @ReinRaus: Круто, завидую.

Comment: непонятым осталось только поведение в самом php: Если исходное выражение `preg_match_all('#([(.*?)]))#s', $text, $result);` работало хотя бы на локальном сервере, то оптимальное: `preg_match_all('#(\(\[((?:[^\]]++|\](?!\)))*)\]\))#s', $text, $result);` вешает его наглухо... Вроде нигде не ошибся?

Comment: @Isaev можно разбираемый текст выложить куда-нибудь? Это на котором зависает.

Comment: @ReinRaus, [тут положил](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/6aG6/XM9unMZHS). В переменную загружаю так: `$text=file_get_contents($fileName, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);`

Comment: @ReinRaus, хм, вообще запутался) Версии php на локальном 5.5, на внешнем 5.2. Циклы убрал вообще, прогоняем по 1 разу. Результаты: Внешний сервер: 0.005 : 0.003, bool(false) т.к. второе выражение ничего не находит вообще, возвращается пустой массив! Локальный сервер: на первом выражении вешается и перегружает сервер, второе выполняется нормально с правильным ответом за 0.0199, скрипт один и тот же. Бред какой-то! Но это уже совсем другая проблема, к регуляркам, похоже, отношения не имеет.